# CTE Fast To Select from but Slow to Insert from

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I've got a CTE that does a lot of hard work over tens of thousands of records.

If I just run the select below which uses the CTE it comes back in less than a second.

However if I add the insert line above it, it takes around 30 seconds!  Even though the select is only bringing back 1 or 2 records.

I've tried this with temp tables, real tables, variable tables and they are all the same.

```
INSERT INTO VIPScoreLog --Fast without this line
SELECT 
  vs.CustomerId, 
  vs.VIPScore
FROM CTE_VIPScore vs
LEFT JOIN vw_LatestVIPScores lvs on vs.CustomerId = lvs.CustomerId
WHERE lvs.VIPScore IS NULL 
OR lvs.VIPScore <> vs.VIPScore
```

Any ideas how I can get rid of this 29 second delay?

This on SQL Server 2019

Comment: Could be lots. Indexes on the table, poorly written triggers, a blocking process. You're adding an extra table to the query, so it's not completely comparable to to the `SELECT` without the `INSERT`. I would start by looking at the query plan; which you can share via [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: use an indexed temp table instead of a cte.  cte are used for small query subqueries to be combined more efficiently than the optimizer selects.  ctes allow you to control the execution order

Comment: VIPScoreLog is a brand new empty table with no triggers.  I don't see why it would add any real load to just insert a couple of records here.  Even when it inserts no records its the same.

Comment: Yes, I guess I could try temp tables instead of CTEs, but in my mind the CTE bit is working well, it's just getting the output into a proper table that's slow.

Comment: You need to determine _why_ there is a 30 second delay. We could guess but that's not very useful. Check for blocking, check the wait types involved with the insert, look at the plan...

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you use `select... into... ` syntax?

Comment: All credit to the author, but check out https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/software-vendor-mistakes-with-sql-server-not-getting-parallel-inserts-into-temp-tables/. the tl;dr is to add the TABLOCK query hint to the insert statement to allow for parallelism on the insert. I'd try it on a temp table to validate the approach. You mentioned in another comment that your real table is an new/empty one so the approach might be okay there as well (i.e. won't affect applications currently using the table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Golden Lion, I tried replacing the CTEs with temp tables instead and it's lightning fast.

Not sure I understand why but I guess I'm sorted now.

Thanks everyone for your help.